# VSTS push to Azure Container Registry - getting timouts or "V1 endpoint is not supported"

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-container-registry

Created a Docker Build Task in VSTS to push to Azure Container Registry.

Worked fine yesterday, today I'm getting either an error or a timeout with each retry.

I tried adding a new Registry and build task but getting the same errors.

Error 1 - 
"V1 endpoint is not supported":
[image]

Error 2 - Timeout:
 Some parts of the image push, others timeout until it fails. 
 [image]

Azure Support asked me to post here.

Comment: Set System.Debug to true and queue build, then post the detail log here. What's the result if you push it in your local machine?

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved, I am no longer getting the "Retrying in x seconds" messages or the "V1 endpoint.." message.

Comment: @fhilton how you resolved the issue. I am getting the same errors, any inputs will be helpful

Comment: Hi @RahulKhengare, the error resolved itself. It appears to have been a network issue. See the answer below.

Comment: Thank you @fhilton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSL timeout could be due to network connection issues.

The "V1 endpoint is not supported" error stems from the docker client behavior. Basically docker client will first try to connect to the registry server on V2 endpoint (/v2/); if it can't connection or connection times out, it will try to connect the registry on V1 endpoint (/v1/), in case the registry is an old v1 registry. Azure Container Registry only supports V2 endpoint so if there is request targeting for V1 endpoint, it returns such error message.

Both somehow seemed due to slow connection on TLS. If you see the error consistently, you can contact Azure Container Registry team or Microsoft support team with your subscription information, registry name and time frame of the issue so the team can help to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

TSL timeout is due to slow network connectivity. You can overcome this by decreasing the number of images concurrently getting uploaded in docker daemon. Use --max-concurrent-uploads with dockerd and set the max concurrent upload to 1 and you may also decrease the concurrent download. Help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#options.

For “V1 endpoint is not supported” error, are you using hosted or private pool. If its private pool can you check the docker client installed on the agent where you are getting this error. I have a hunch that it might have an old version of docker client installed on it.”